# How to compare Accesss SQL result to SQL Server results efficiently?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to convert my Access query to SQL views. I can see how many records are returned in both cases easily. But it is getting difficult to make sure the record matches as I have to check it manually. Also I don't check every single record so there might be some conversion error that I did not notice.

Is there a way to check at least some segment of the result automatically?

Comment: No, there's not.

Comment: Perhaps Find Unmatched queries will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a way, you are asking the wrong question.

When you migrate the data to sql server, then at that point you assumed all data made it to sql server. I suppose you could do a one-time check of the record counts.

At that point, you then link the tables (that likely pointed to an access back end) to now pointing to sql server.

At this point, all of the existing queries in Access should and will work fine. ZERO need exists to test and check this after a migration.

For existing forms that are bound to a table (a linked table), then you DO NOT NEED to create views on sql server and this is simply not done nor required.

The ONLY time you will convert an access query to a view is if the access query runs slow.

For a simple query say on a table of 1 million invoices, you can continue to use the Access query (that is running against the linked tables). If you do a query such as

Select * from tblInvoices where invoiceNum = 12345

Then Access will ONLY pull the one record down the network pipe. So ZERO need and performance gains will occur by converting this query to a view (do not do this!!! – you are simply wasting valuable time and money).

However, for a complex query with multiple joins, and multiple tables (which are NOT in general used for a form), then you do want to convert such quires to a view, and then given the view the SAME name as what the access (client side) query had.

So you not “out of the blue” going to wind up with a large number of views on sql server after a migration.

You migrate the data, link the tables. At that point 99% of your application will work just fine as before. After I migration you DO NOT NEED TO create any views.

Creating views is a “after the fact” and occurs AFTER you have the application running. So views are NOT created until such time you have the application up and running. (And deployed).

To get your access application to work with sql server you DO NOT create ANY views. You do not even create ONE view.

You migrate the data, link the tables, and now your application should work.

You ONLY start creating views for access queries that run slow.

So for example, you might have a report that now runs slow. The reason is that while access does a good job for most existing quires (that you don’t have to change), for some, you find that the access client does a “less than ideal” job of running that query.

So you flip that query in access into sql view mode, cut + paste that sql into the sql manager, (creating a view). You then modify the syntax of the query. For some sql, it might be simply less effort to bring up the query in the access designer, and then bring up the sql designer in sql server, and simply re-create the sql from scratch in place of the cut + paste idea. (Both approaches work fine – it depends on how “crazy” the sql is you are working with as to which approach you find works better (try both – see what suits you best). Some like to cut+psate the sql, and others like to simply look at the graphical designer in both cases (on two monitors) and work that way.

At this point, after you created the sql query (the view), you simply run that view, and look at the record count. You then run the query that you have on the access client, and if it returns the same number of records, then in 999.9% of cases, you can be rather confident that the sql query (the view) produces the same results as the client query. You now delete (or re-name) the access query, link to the view (giving it the same name as the access query, and you are now done.

The 2, or 20 places that used that access client query will now be using the view. You should not have to worry or modify one thing in Access after having done this.

Now that the view is working, you then re-deploy your access front end to all workstations (I assume you have some means to update the access application part – just like you did even when not using sql server).

At this point, users are all happy and working.

If in the next day or so, you now find another report that runs slow (most will not), then that access query becomes a possible choice by you to convert to a view.

So out an application of say 200 quires in access, you will in general likely only have to convert 2-10 of them to a views. The VAST majority of the access saved queries DO NOT AND SHOULD NOT be converted to views. It is a waste of time to convert an access query that runs perfectly well and performs well to a view.

So your question suggests that you have to convert a “lot” of Access quires to views. This is NEVER the case nor is it a requirement.

So the amount of times that you need to convert an access query to a view is going to be quite rare. Most forms are based on a table. Or now a linked table to sql server. In these cases you do NOT want to convert to a view, and you don’t need to.

So the answer here is simply run the access query, and then run the view. They are both working on the same data (you using linked tables and the access queries will HIT those linked tables and work just fine). If the access client using the linked tables to sql server returns the same number of records as your view on sql server, then as noted, you are 999.8% done, and you are now safe to re-name the access query, and link to the view with the same name.

However, the number of times you do this after a migration is VERY low and VERY rare.

You don’t convert any existing access saved query to a view unless running that query in access is taking excessive time.

As noted, for “not too complex” sql quires (ones that don’t involve joins between too many tables), you will not see nor find a benefit by converting that access query to a view. You KEEP and use the existing Access quires as they are.

You only want to spend time on the “few” queries that run slow, the rest do NOT need to be modified.

For an existing form that is bound to a table (or now a linked table), such forms are NOT to be changed to views – they are editing tables directly, (or linked tables), and REALLY REALLY need to remain as such. Attempting to covert such forms using a linked table to a view is HUGE mess, and something that will not help performance, but worse only introduce potential 100’s of issues and bugs into your existing application, and you doing something that is NOT required.

Because you will create so VERY FEW views, then a automated approach is not required. You simply make the one query, run it, and then run the existing access query (client side). If they both return the same number of reocrds, then it is a cold chance in hell day that you need further testing. You going to be creating one view at a time, and creating these views over a "longer" period of time. You NEVER migrate access and then migrate a large number of queries to sql server. That is NOT how a migration works.

You migrate, link the tables. At that point your application should work fine. You  get it working (and not yet have created any views). You get the application deployed. ONLY after you have everything working just fine do you THEN start to introduce views into the mix and picture. As noted, because you only ever going to work with introducing ONE view into the application, and this will occur "over time" while users are using the existing and working application, then little need for some automated approach and test is required.  As I stated, with 200+ access client queries, you should not need to convert more then about 5, maybe 10 to views - the rest are to remain as they are now and untouched and unmodified by you.

Comment: You are awesome